# RAM compatibility

Tags: memory, specifications

Is there a website where I can look up what kind of RAM my computer has, and what kind of RAM would I need to buy to ensure compatibility ?

Answer (score 9):

I've always used [`Crucial`](http://www.crucial.com) as a way to quickly drill down by manufacturer and model, even if I don't buy it from them.  Their Memory Advisor Tool will tell you the number of slots on your system, as well as what type of memory (speed, number of pins, size, etc.).

The next best option in my opinion is to look at your manufacturers support site to see if they list the information specific to your system (e.g. if its a Dell you can use your service tag to look up your specs, which would include information on memory compatability).

Comment: I've  used this a few times as well, works great.  Had one issue with it and I think an older model pc it said in the test that it could use better ram than what the product specs said.  But that was one rare instance.

Answer (score 2):

Several of the major direct to consumer RAM retailers such as [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/) and [Kingston Technology](http://www.kingston.com/), have RAM type search tools for major pre-built systems.

For pre-built systems the System's User Guide from the manufacturer or distributor's website will normally include this information. E.g. HP and Dell.

The User Guide for a given motherboard of a small-shop or home built PC will also detail what type of RAM you need or want. Some manufactures even offer lists of tested compatible or recommended models (Asus does for example).

Answer (score -1):

You can also find out what kind of RAM (and other types of hardware) is in your computer with software like [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy) - if RAM was changed in your computer, it won't help you to know which RAM was inside it originally.

For maximum compatibility, you should buy the same RAM module from the same manufacturer - if you can't do that, you should buy a RAM which runs at the same, or higher speeds - but perhaps more importantly, try to match CAS latencies (CL).

Regarding speeds, a RAM running at a higher speed should be able to match lower speeds. CAS latencies are a bit more complex, and you can change them in your BIOS/UEFI, if it's not locked. Lower CAS is generally better for performance (when talking about the same RAM speeds), since your computer should be able to increase a RAM's CAS if needed (in other words, make RAM slower).

Usually, your computer should be able to make some compromise between 2 different RAM modules on its own ... but if you're worried, try to match CAS latencies as well as RAM speed. Every RAM module supports multiple speeds and CAS latencies.